# How to achieve equal horizontal AND vertical margins, AND equal column width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout

So that when I stretch or shrink the browser's width,

- All columns will stretch proportionally and fill the parent container's width 100%
- The horizontal margins would of course, also stretch proportionally
- BUT I want the vertical margins to match the width of the horizontal margins automatically.

My markup:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">...</div>
   <div class="child">...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .parent{
       margin-right: -2%; /* to compensate for the unwanted margin of what ends up being the right-most element */
    }
    .child{
       display: inline-block;
       width: 23% /* I want 4 columns, so it'll be a little less than 25%, right? */
       margin-right: 2% /* So width + margin-right percent add up to 25% */
       margin-bottom: ? /* Can't say 2% because it's NOT 2% of the parent container's width */
       height: 100px; /* constant value */
    }
```

If possible, I don't want to create extra markup or use JavaScript to fix achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem right now?

Comment: The margin-bottom and margin-right will not end up being equal pixel space because margin-bottom as a percent will be percentage of the parent height. Margin-right as a percent will be percentage of the parent's width.

Comment: And I want to guarantee that the space between the children, in all directions will be equal.

Comment: have you tried using flexbox? & vh for height?

Comment: ok I see you are a backend guy. What is your browser support? If only modern, your issue is solved by 6 lines of css

Comment: Doesn't flexbox only do one row or one column at a time, though?

Comment: @MickaelCaruso amount of items can be controled by ``flex-basis`` property that accepts ``width`` in ``%`` or ``px``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not necessary for you to have percentaged margins, you can try setting static margins (for example 20px) and calculated width (25% - 20px);

```
.parent{
   margin-right: -20px;
}
.child{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: calc(25% - 20px);
   margin-right: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I've not seen or heard of the calc function before.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox & viewport height solution

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/bdZVow)

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10vh; //Margin bottom of 10% of viewport height applied to the container instead of the item
}

.item {
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px; //Flexbox automatically handels that (may wanna switch off for the last child)
    background-color: tomato;
    flex: 1; //All items take equal width to fill the container
}
```

P.S. I didn't get what you meant by "equal horizontal & vertical margins", but if you meant that horizontal margin == vertical margin, then replace `10vh` with `20px.`

Comment: Exactly what I meant - calculated width and height in pixels of horizontal and vertical, respectively.